# File not deleting

Tags: java, file

So, I am trying to delete a file, but it doesn't let me... here is my code:

```
private static final File file = new File("data.dat");

public static void recreate() {
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        if (file.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Huh, what now?");
        }

        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As is not suspected, it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Huh, what now?
```

Any help? What am I doing wrong (It probably is just a derp...)?

Comment: Why this `SaveFile` before `file.exists()`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun it is the class name, removed it for clarity

Comment: Possibly the file is open somewhere. Did you make sure to always `close()` your file handles, or use the try-with-resources block?

Comment: I suspect you're not showing us all the relevant code.

Comment: The file is not open, and all the resources are closed.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29 and check the errors

Comment: Programmatically create a file, check its existence, dump the file-information object and subsequently delete it. If that scenario yields an error then you have an interesting case, else it comes down to your Java-VM, [file]/system, handles and privileges.

Comment: From what I experienced, File.exists() *could* return a false positive, where trying to open (read only) should be safe to determine, wheter the file actually exists.

Comment: You can try to print out the actual exception that is thrown instead of custom text to narrow down the error?

Comment: You're sure you don't have a text editor session or some such open on that file?

Comment: Reboot the system and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have write permissions on that file. Here is how you can check write permissions on that file using [`File#canWrite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) before trying to delete that file:

```
if (!file.canWrite()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Sorry I don't have right permissions!");
}
// now you can try to delete it
if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
}
```

**EDIT:** You also need read/write/execute permissions on parent directory. You can add these checks also:

```
if (!file.exists())
    throw new RuntimeException("file doesn't exist!");

File parent = file.getParentFile();

if (!parent.canRead() || !parent.canWrite() || !parent.canExecute())
    throw new RuntimeException("Sorry I don't have right permissions on dir!");

if (!file.canWrite())
    throw new RuntimeException("Sorry I don't have write permission on file!");

// now you can try to delete it
if (file.delete()) // check return value
    System.out.println("file deleted!!!");
 else
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to delete the file");
```

Comment: But in theory delete throws an exception if it cannot delete the file: "Note that the Files class defines the delete method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted"

Comment: Still not working. When I change the code to add the canWrite line, it still throws the Huh, what now? Exception.

Comment: @HotLicks That's the Files class. File just returns a boolean for success.

Comment: @HotLicks He's not using Files. He's using the instance method on the File object, which returns a boolean. It does not throw an IOException.

Comment: @Boann: Can you check return value of delete() method?

Comment: Not just write permissions on the file, but you may need write permission on its containing directory,

Comment: @Boann - Ah, yes, I see.  (The spec likes to do that sort of thing and it totally confuses you.)  So the code should be testing the return code from `delete`.

Comment: @anubhava It's not me.

Comment: @Boann: My apologies sir it was meant for OP

Comment: Ok can you print `file.getCanonicalPath()` to see what it prints before delete operation.

Comment: @anubhava C:\Users\<My Name>\Eclipse projects\debt\Debt\data.dat

Comment: Is `data.dat` a real file? I mean is it not a shortcut or something? Can you delete that file directly from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you asked, but since you recreate the file anyway, how about:

```
public static void recreate() {
    try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        // empty
    } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```